# TeXlipse installation problems

Tags: editors, texlipse, eclipse

I have installed the most recent version of [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) (version 1.3.0.20100617-0521, build id 20100617-1415) and am trying to install the [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net) plugin. I've followed the [installation guide](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/installation.html) thoroughly (although in my build of Eclipse the option was called "Install new software..." instead of "Software Updates/Find and install", but I assume that's because their screenshots are old...) and the installation seems to have gone through fine - no errors, and the Help/About pages suggest that TeXlipse (version 1.4) is installed and working.

However, there are no configuration options available, so I can't follow [step 2 of the installation guide](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/configuration.html), and when I try to open a *.tex document my old tex editor (TeXWorks) opens it instead.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Dima: Windows 7 Pro ed.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've tried just now.

Yeap the screenshots are old. I have added the repository, clicked on the TeXlipse and went throught the installation (downaloding, confirming unsigned content etc.)

Upto the part where Ecplipse suggest to restart itself. Choose to restart eclipse.

After the restart the options are available in the "Window -> Preferences -> Texlipse" You can use the filter in the preferences dialog to search for "Tex" and texlipse shows up.

This is tested with "Version: 3.5.2" of eclipse.

Comment: After I choose to restart Eclipse, no such options are available. I'm using Eclipse 3.6.0, TeXlipse 1.4.1, and Windows 7.

Comment: Btw it's the Java EE version of Eclipse. Does that matter?